# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00936: missing expression TALEND

Tags: java

estoy obteniendo el error java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00936: missing expression en talend en Talend usando la siguiente consulta en un tOracle_input:

```
SELECT /*+ ALL_ROWS */
                    IC_TM.ID ID_TELEIC
                    ,DECODE(EST_O.SERVICIO_ID,1,22,2,26,3,13,4,12,5,25,6,33,7,15,8,11) SERV_SALUD
                    ,DP.RUT RUN
                    ,DP.DV DV
                    ,DP.NOMBRES NOMBRES
                    ,DP.APELLIDO_PAT PRIMER_APELLIDO
                    ,DP.APELLIDO_MAT SEGUNDO_APELLIDO
                    ,TO_CHAR(DP.FECHA_NAC,'DD/MM/RRRR') FECHA_NACI
                    ,DECODE(DP.SEXO_ID, 1, '1', 2, '2', 3, '3', '9') SEXO
                    ,DECODE(DT.PREVISION_ID, 32, '1', 35, '1', 36, '1', 37, '1', 46, '1', 34, '3', 47, '2', 45, '1', 48, '3', 31, '3', 49, '1', DT.PREVISION_ID) PREVISION
                    ,DECODE(DP.PRAIS, 'S', '1', '2') PRAIS
                    ,DECODE(MAX(PROV.REGIONES_ID), 346, '14', 266, '10', 314, '11', 233, '9', 329, '12', 345, '13', 142, '7', 60, '5', 176, '8', 105, '6', 15, '2', 41, '4', MAX(PROV.REGIONES_ID)) REGION
                    ,NVL(MAX(COM2.DESCRIPCION), '') CIUDAD
                    ,NVL(MAX(COM2.CODIGO), '') COMUNA_RESIDENCIA
                    ,MAX(DECODE(DP.UR, 'u', '1', 'r', '2', 'U', '1', 'R', '2', 'sd')) RURALIDAD
                    ,CIE10.DESCRIPCION SOSP_DIAG
                    ,TO_CHAR(IC_TM.FECHA_TIM,'DD/MM/RRRR') F_ENTRADA
                    ,EST_O.CODIGO_ESTAB_FONAS ESTABL_ORIGEN
                    ,EST_D.CODIGO_ESTAB_FONAS ESTABL_DESTIN
                    ,'1' TIPO_PREST
                    ,SE.CODIGO_FONASA PRESTA_MIN
                    ,SE.DESCRIPCION PRESTA_ESTABL
                    ,'' PRESTA_MIN_SALIDA
                    ,'' CAUSA_SALIDA
                    ,'' F_SALIDA
                    ,'' ESTABL_OTOR_AT
                    ,'' FOTO
                    ,'' ESTAB_ATENCION
                    ,'' RUN_PROF_RESOLV
                    ,'' DV_PROF_RESOLV
                    ,21 ESTADO_IC_ID
                    ,DL.FONO_CASA FONO_CASA
                    ,DL.FONO_MOVIL FONO_MOVIL
                    ,UPPER(DL.DIRECCION) DIRECCION
                    ,PE.RUT RUT_PROF
                    ,PE.DV DV_PROF
                FROM
                    TELEMEDICINA.INTERCONSULTA_TIM IC_TM
                    INNER JOIN REFCENTRAL.PERSONAS PE ON IC_TM.PERSONA_ID = PE.ID
                    INNER JOIN DBGES.DBGES_CIE10 CIE10 ON IC_TM.DIAG_CIE10_1_ID = CIE10.ID
                    INNER JOIN REFCENTRAL.DATOS_LOCALES DL ON IC_TM.DATOS_LOCALES_ID = DL.ID
                    INNER JOIN REFCENTRAL.DATOS_PACIENTE DP ON DL.DATOS_PACIENTE_ID = DP.ID
                    INNER JOIN REFCENTRAL.COMUNAS COM ON DP.COMUNA_ID = COM.ID
                    INNER JOIN REFCENTRAL.PROVINCIAS PROV ON COM.PROVINCIAS_ID = PROV.ID
                    LEFT JOIN TELEMEDICINA.INTERCONSULTA_TIM_IC TIM_IC ON TIM_IC.INTERCONSULTA_TIM_ID = IC_TM.ID
                    LEFT JOIN REFCENTRAL.DATOS_TITULAR DT ON DP.DATOS_TITULAR_ID = DT.ID
                    LEFT JOIN REFCENTRAL.ESTABLECIMIENTO EST_O ON IC_TM.ESTAB_ORIGEN_ID = EST_O.ID
                    LEFT JOIN REFCENTRAL.ESTABLECIMIENTO EST_D ON IC_TM.ESTAB_DESTINO_ID = EST_D.ID
                    LEFT JOIN REFCENTRAL.JERARQUIA_ESPEC JER ON IC_TM.JERARQUIA_DESTINO_ID = JER.ID
                    LEFT JOIN REFCENTRAL.SUBESPECIALIDADES SE ON JER.SUBESPECIALIDAD_ID = SE.ID
                    LEFT JOIN REFCENTRAL.COMUNAS COM2 ON EST_O.COMUNA_ID = COM2.ID
                WHERE
                    IC_TM.ESTAB_ORIGEN_ID <> 68
                    AND IC_TM.ESTAB_ORIGEN_ID <> 167
                    AND IC_TM.ID IN
                        (
                            SELECT
                                TIM_M.INTERCONSULTA_TIM_ID 
                            FROM
                                TELEMEDICINA.INTERCONSULTA_TIM_MOVS TIM_M
                            WHERE
                                --TIM_M.ESTADO_BANDEJA_ID <> 7 /* CERRADAS */
                                --AND TIM_M.ESTADO_BANDEJA_ID <> 10 /* RECHAZADAS */
                                --AND TIM_M.ESTADO_BANDEJA_ID <> 15 /* ANULADAS */
                                TIM_M.ESTADO_BANDEJA_ID = 1 /* POR ENVIAR */
                                AND TIM_M.FECHA_MOD BETWEEN TO_DATE(?, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE(?, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
                            GROUP BY
                                TIM_M.INTERCONSULTA_TIM_ID
                        )
                        AND IC_TM.ESTADO_BANDEJA_ID <> 7
                        AND IC_TM.ESTADO_BANDEJA_ID <> 10
                        AND IC_TM.ESTADO_BANDEJA_ID <> 15
                        AND IC_TM.FECHA_TIM BETWEEN TO_DATE(?, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE(?, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
                        AND IC_TM.ACTIVO = 'S'
                GROUP BY
                    IC_TM.ID
            ,EST_O.SERVICIO_ID
                    ,DP.RUT
                    ,DP.DV
                    ,DP.NOMBRES
                    ,DP.APELLIDO_PAT
                    ,DP.APELLIDO_MAT
                    ,DP.FECHA_NAC
                    ,DP.SEXO_ID
                    ,DT.PREVISION_ID
                    ,DP.PRAIS
                    ,COM.DESCRIPCION
                    ,CIE10.DESCRIPCION
                    ,IC_TM.FECHA_TIM
                    ,EST_O.CODIGO_ESTAB_FONAS
                    ,EST_D.CODIGO_ESTAB_FONAS
                    ,SE.CODIGO_FONASA
                    ,SE.DESCRIPCION
                    ,DL.FONO_CASA
                    ,DL.FONO_MOVIL
                    ,DL.DIRECCION
                    ,PE.RUT
                    ,PE.DV
                ORDER BY
                    IC_TM.FECHA_TIM DESC
```

Comment: Has probado haciendo un Throws sql exception  ?

Comment: la consulta en toad funciona bien

Comment: La consulta la ejecutas con un PreparedStatement?

Comment: En Toad funciona, pero te fijaste que en tu programa tuvieras exactamente la misma consulta?

Comment: sí me fijé solo puse las fechas

Comment: no la ejecuto con un PreparedStatement